# Select statement to extract the variable name

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to identify the username from a range and then return the `FilePerUser` name.

When I run the code, the open file name only identifies the `FileDir` variable (\network\test folder\destination) not including the `FilePerUser` from the select statement.

```vb
Sub datapull_manual()
    
    Dim FilePerUser As String
    Dim User As Variant
    User = Worksheets("prp").Range("v2")
    
    Dim FileDir As String
    FileDir = "\\network\test folder\destination\"
    
    'user names to automatically open file as per every user
    
    Select Case FilePerUser
    Case User = "Mo"
    FilePerUser = "k111"
    Case User = "To"
    FilePerUser = "k222"
    Case User = "Vo"
    FilePerUser = "k333"
    End Select
    
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=(FileDir & FilePerUser)
    Columns("A:S").Copy
    Windows("Test.xlsb").Activate
    Sheets("test123").Select
    Cells.Select
    Range("A2").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
end sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your `Select`-statement:

```
Select Case user
    Case "Mo"
        filePerUser = "k111"
    Case "To"
        filePerUser = "k222"
    Case "Vo"
        filePerUser = "k333"
    Case else
        MsgBox "User not found"
        exit sub
End Select
```

Answer (score 2):

As @FunThomas pointed out - you're using the wrong syntax in the Select Case statement.
You're also not adding the file extension to the file name.  Currently you're looking for a file called "k111" not "k111.xlsx".

This code should work:

```
Sub datapull_manual()

    Dim FilePerUser As String
    Dim User As Variant
    User = Worksheets("prp").Range("v2")

    Dim FileDir As String
    FileDir = "\\network\test folder\destination\"

    'user names to automatically open file as per every user

    'Change Case to look at 'User' variable.
    'Case "Mo", not 'Case User = "Mo"'
    Select Case User
        Case "Mo"
            FilePerUser = "K111.xlsx"
        Case "To"
            FilePerUser = "k222.xlsx"
        Case "Vo"
            FilePerUser = "k333.xlsx"
    End Select

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=(FileDir & FilePerUser)
    Columns("A:S").Copy
    Windows("Test.xlsb").Activate
    Sheets("test123").Select
    Cells.Select
    Range("A2").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

The bottom part of your code could be improved by referencing the workbooks with variables:

```
Sub datapull_manual()

    Dim FilePerUser As String
    Dim User As Variant
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim WB1 As Workbook

    User = Worksheets("prp").Range("v2")

    Dim FileDir As String
    FileDir = "\\network\test folder\destination\"

    'user names to automatically open file as per every user

    'Change Case to look at 'User' variable.
    'Case "Mo", not 'Case User = "Mo"'
    Select Case User
        Case "Mo"
            FilePerUser = "k111.xlsx"
        Case "To"
            FilePerUser = "k222.xlsx"
        Case "Vo"
            FilePerUser = "k333.xslx"
    End Select

    'Open & set reference to the workbook.
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileDir & FilePerUser)
    Set WB1 = Workbooks("Test.xlsb") 'Set reference to Test workbook.
    'Set WB1 = ThisWorkbook 'If Test.xlsb is the workbook containing this code.

    'Use references to copy data - no need to activate or select anything.
    WB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:S").Copy _
        Destination:=WB1.Worksheets("Test123").Range("A2")

End Sub
```